# How to write data in the dataframe into single .parquet file(both data & metadata in single file) to Amazon S3?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am trying to write DF into single parquet file based on some key(partition by name) to S3. My requirement is to append the data to same parquet file for each run.

This is code i used but this code created the folders for each name inside that folder for each run its creating new parquet files. However, my requirement is to write to a single file.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("name").format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Append).option("fileType", "parquet").save("s3n://ialert-data/store-streaming-data/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use repartition not partition by and coalesce after repartitioning.

```
df.repartition(df("name")).coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet("s3n://ialert-data/store-streaming-data/")
```

Comment: thank you for your response. i have tried your method still its creating new parquet file for-each run and its not separating the data based on name. I need files based on name and for-each run we need to append to the same files. Please help.

Comment: If you are using `write.mode(SaveMode.Append)` it will always just add a file each time its run.  If you want a single file, you need to load all the data, repartition, and then write it all back as a single file.

Comment: I have tried the about suggestion, its possible to merge multiple parquet files to single large file. However, for the next run again its creating new file. I dint find anyways to write into single parquet file for every run.

Comment: Any AWS service or any program that can write to a existing parquet file in append mode.